# How to run Jekyll plugin after include tags?

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I use `{% include text.md %}` in my posts to include some often typed paragraphs.

I have a `Generator` plugin that makes some text replacement in post contents.

However, the text inside the included files (e.g. `text.md`) is not processed by this plugin.

How can I run the plugin *after* includes are performed but *before* html is rendered? Or how could I do things differently to make it work?

Comment: What is the generator exactly doing (input, output) ? Did you need to create new pages ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel It simply replaces some keywords by others. for instance replace `machine learning` with `<em>machine-learning</em>`

Comment: Why don't you use the `{{ content | replace: "foo", "bar" }}` filter ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel I have several hundreds of keywords that are aggregated from post content and replacement contain liquid tags

Comment: Curious to know more. How did you aggregate ? What are you replacing ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel I'm building an index for a technical documentation where each technical term is hyperlinked to it's definition.

Comment: @DavidJacquel now that you know, help me 

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. But I still don't know what are your input and output or what is supposed to be processed in your includes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jekyll processes a site in distinct "phases".

```
  reset >> read >> generate >> render >> cleanup >> write
```

A `Generator` subclass is generally used to "generate" objects (Pages or Documents) that are then rendered based on the `priority`defined for the generator.

An include tag (or any Liquid constructs) is "rendered" in the subsequent phase.

Unfortunately, **you cannot alter the "raw content" of a file in the middle of the rendering phase**.
Jekyll provides you with just a `:pre_render` hook to manipulate unrendered content of a file.

Comment: So what can I do instead?